# After install, python test script fails

Tags: python, testing

I installed Python 2.7 on my Windows laptop. When I run the test command

```
python -c 'from... evernote client...`
```

it says from is invalid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `from....evernote client` is indeed not valid Python syntax. I suggest using a different test command.

Comment: if you're just checking the interpreter is there, just try something simpler like `python -c "print 2 +1"`

Comment: Post the exact command you are trying.

Comment: What is the full command you are running?

Comment: Did you mean [`python -c 'from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient'`](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/start/python.php) ?

Comment: yes to the last statement on python

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after many trys - once I am in the python console I don't need the first work python and I don't need -c. All I had to do is remove the quote marks around the statement and it worked fine.